# outputting multiple things to a file powershell

Tags: powershell

I have an array and a foreach loop, it loops through each element and gets all my information and outputs it to a file Out-File text.txt. However it only outputs the last elements data. How can I make it so it all data from all elements is in the file?

Comment: +1 for @EBGreen. It sounds likely that you're overwriting when you expect to be appending.

Comment: This question lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Please include the [relevant parts of the code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain in specific terms what you're trying to accomplish and how your results differ from the desired results, and provide sample data. Please read this advice on [ask] and Jon Skeet's blog post [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx). Pay special attention to the "Golden Rule", though I highly advise you to read the entire article.

Comment: As @alroc says, you should be using `+=` to append elements to the array. If you're assigning using `=` you are overwriting the contents of the array.

Comment: @KeithHill, I don't think we have enough information to say that it's definitely an array being appended to. I read it as he's using `Out-File` to write the data immediately to file - but if he's not using `-Append`, it'll just keep overwriting the data. Either way, it's most likely an overwrite vs. append problem.